# Why is my angular-ui-tour not finding the steps of my detached tour?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-tour

I'm using [angular-ui-tour](http://benmarch.github.io/angular-ui-tour/#/docs) to enable my project to have multiple tours within the same DOM, because is has a detached tour option which I need to do so.

My dependencies (relevant for this issue):

- angular 1.5.7
- bootstrap ^3.3.6
- angular-bootstrap ^2.0.0
- angular-ui-tour ^0.6.2

I can initialize the tour with the according config, but when I check for steps, no steps are found.

When I try to start the tour, the error confirms this: 'No step.'-error.
What am I missing here?

```js
angular.module('myApp',['bm.uiTour']).run(['uiTourService',
  function(uiTourService) {
    //setup the tour
    uiTourService.createDetachedTour('general', {
      name: 'general',
      backdrop: true,
      debug: true
    });

    //testing
    var uitour = uiTourService.getTourByName('general');
    console.log(uitour); // Object {_name: undefined, initialized: true}

    //test tour steps
    console.log(uitour._getSteps()); // []

    //test tour start
    uitour.start().then(function(data) {
      //tour start succeeded
    }, function(error) {
      //tour start failed
      console.log(error); // No steps.
    });

  }
]);
```

```html
<body ui-tour>
  <div tour-step tour-step-belongs-to="general" 
       tour-step-order="1" 
       tour-step-title="step 1" 
       tour-step-content="this is step 1">
  </div>
  <div tour-step tour-step-belongs-to="general" 
       tour-step-order="2" 
       tour-step-title="step 2" 
       tour-step-content="this is step 2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've come to the point where I noticed another bower component was scrambling with the tour (I had to uninstall angular-bootstrap-tour). Now I see the first step, but no content or buttons are shown.

Comment: I can toggle through the steps using the hotkeys, so the steps are attached. The buttons are just not shown on the step, same goes for the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this question. Apparently this is a known bug of [angular-ui-tour](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour) and will be fixed in the next patch.

For more information about this question, I can refer you to the [issue on the GitHub](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-ui-tour/issues/90).

For now, you can resolve the issue by making the following change in the angular-ui-tour tourStep directive:

```js
//Add step to tour (old)
scope.tourStep = step;
scope.tour = scope.tour || ctrl;

//Add step to tour (new)
scope.tourStep = step;
scope.tour = ctrl;
```